# Man in elevator, holding it, on a scale

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image: elevator pulley system]

This is the scenario where my mass is $60 kg$, the mass of the elevator is $30kg$, and due to a malfunction, I have to hold myself and the elevator at rest. The question is, if there is a weighing scale under me, (of negligible mass), then what force will it measure (in newtons)?

My approach:
The total mass of the system is $90kg$ which is approximately $900 N$ for equilibrium, tension in the rope is $900N$ because I am giving a downward force of $900N$, so according to Newton's 3rd Law, upward force on me by the rope must be $900N$. This means I should go up, and the weighing scale must not show any reading. But that is not among the options to choose from.  Guidance rather than a direct answer would be appreciated.

Comment: if it's MC, could you give us the options and we may tell you which is correct and why

Comment: Make separate FBD for each , it can be solved easilly. This approach is correct, but $2T=900$ will be correct.

Comment: @007, why 2t?? isnt Tension in string constant?

Comment: a)250N b)200N c)150N d)100N

Comment: Accepting the answer giving just the calculation was a dumb action. Even without FBD that answer can't be understood. Also, i feel sorry for u if you can't even solve a linear equation on your own. Unaccept my answer was really BAD.

Comment: @007 Are you talking about me accepting siddhant's answer? If so, I did that because I think it is the shortest way to do it. MOREOVER, you both are saying the same thing, ie 2T is balancing the wt of the system. The elaborate FBDs are really just saying that 2T is the total upward force. AND, the FBDs you drew were a little confusing because the N is in two directions, and that seems like it will cancel out, as I commented.

Comment: @007 I also didnt know you could accept just one answer. I liked both of them so I accepted both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can actually use $300 - T = 0$ *(1)* for equilibrium of the lift and $600 -T = 0$ *(2)* for equilibrium of the man as both systems are at rest.

Adding *(1)* and *(2)*

$900- 2T = 0$

$T = 450 N$

Taking into account the system of the man, the man exerts a force downwards and tension pulls him upwards.

Thus total force downward in the man's system is $600 N - 450 N = 150 N$

The reading of the weighing machine is $150 N$

Comment: I think it's important to remember that the piezoresistor in the scale will measure the net force that is applied to it by your feet. Yes, you feel 150N down, but being part of the elevator, it feels 150N up. Applying Newton's 3rd law, that means (assuming it isn't moving) that the piezoresistor would experience a net force of 300N applied on top of it, and that's what it would read.

Comment: No, if I push downward on a scale with a weight of 150N, it reads 150N. Otherwise its a broken scale.

Comment: But those two equations give two different values of Tension. T=300 and T=600

Answer (score 2):

> [image: FBD]

Now these two equations can be solved to get the $N$ , by eliminating $T$ . Remember, only the normal force is reading of the elevator.

Comment: @SaurabhRaje See the FBD  and you'll find it's $2T$. Solving you get $c) $ option.

Comment: do i assume that the normal force N there is on the weighing scale?
If yes, isnt it cancelling out??
Please make a FBD for the weighing scale, so that I can see what exactly is the resultant force on it.

Comment: FBD will include Two normal forces equal to $N$ . On top surface , it acts downward and on bottom surface directed upwards.

Comment: so the weighing scale should experience no net force?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: Yes,assumed it's mass-less.

Comment: so if theres no net force on the scale, then how is it showing 150N??

Comment: Assume it to be a inverted spring balance.The net force on it is Zero but the compression is $N/K$. Which can be measured to be the value of the mass placed on it.To get complete working you can ask a new question.

Comment: then wont that be 2N/K??

Answer (score 1):

The total force down is 900N. Thus, the total force up must be 900N. For the rope to be in equilibrium, the force up on each side of the pulley is 450N.

Your force down is 600N, the elevator's force down is 300N. If we carry through the math, that means your net force is 150N down and the elevator's net force is 150N up.

Assuming the weigh scale is considered part of the elevator, it would show 300N. In other words, your mass minus the elevator's mass.

**Edit**

Based on the options provided, I would say you should select the 150N option. However, I believe that is wrong. If we symbolize the masses instead of use numbers, then that answer implies the following:

The force due to gravity of you and the elevator is $-m_1g$ and $-m_2g$ respectively. Thus, in equilibrium, the tension on each side of the pulley would be $g(m_1+m_2)\over2$. And the reading on the scale then is $g(m_1-m_2)\over2$, or the normal force on you as 007 put it.

I believe that this is wrong because in the limit where the mass of the elevator, $m_2$ goes to 0, then it would suggest that the scale reads $gm_1\over2$, or half your mass when, in that limit, it should read your full mass.

What I believe is left out is that due to the tension from the rope, the elevator has a net force upwards and, when combined with your net force downward, the relative normal force the scale would need to provide is a sum of the two, in other words it is $g(m_1-m_2)$, your mass minus the mass of the elevator.

Comment: (-1) $300N$ is not even in options. See my answer You'll get  it.Correct it.

Comment: can I have that -1 taken off now?

Comment: Still, when the mass $m_2$ goes zero, tention does not and $N$ would be half the mass, no doubt in it.

Comment: but the scale must be considered as part of the elevator, so you can't just take into consideration your normal force, but its normal force as well.

Comment: the weigh scale experiences a net force up from the tension in the rope as well as the upwards normal force corresponding to your downwards net force. While the answer he should select is 150N, the real answer is that the scale should read 300N. Get me a piece of wood, a rope, and a pulley and I'll prove it

Comment: Reminding you that the commentator doesn't get notified unless you say `@commentator`. For example, use `@Crazy` to ping me. A quick advice that *-1 don't make your posts look so bad, instead it gets more attention* ;-)

Comment: Hmm... I have removed -1 but that still don't satisfy me. The answer would be $(m_1-m_2)g/2$ regardless of $m_2$.

Comment: @CrazyBuddy I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also, @007, this new info makes me feel as though I should apologize for getting overly defensive about a -1. Sorry dude.